# can anyone tell me why I got this?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider_android'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.19\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider_android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you have a healthy internet connection.**

- Make sure you have latest version of package [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) installed in pubspec.yaml.
- Go to File menu and click invalidate Cache.
- Re-open your project and run `flutter clean` command in the terminal from the root of your project.
- Then run `flutter pub get`

Now again build your project